# Python 3.6 - How to search through a 2D list and return true or false if an item matches user input

Tags: python-3.x

I am using EDX to start learning python and I am stuck in a project that requires me to create a tic tac toe game.

I believe I have managed to complete most of the functions but when I tried to run the function that checks whether a position is available to be marked as X or O, I always get a false reading. It returns true only for the 7 and not for the rest of the items.

```
board = [['7', '8', '9'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3']]

location = input(" Turn, select a number (1, 9): ")

def available(location, board):
    for row in board:
        for col in row:
            if col==location:
                return True
            else:
                return False

print(available(location,board))
```

I decided to separate the function from the rest of the code. The code above should be able to search the 2D list and if it finds the number that the user has entered to return true or false. When it does that another function is executed to change that number to X or O depending the player. I tried to run the function without the function and with print instead of return and works fine.

```
board = [['7', '8', '9'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3']]

location = input(" Turn, select a number (1, 9): ")
for row in board:
    for col in row:
        if col==location:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i don't see anything wrong here can you please elaborate your problem a bit more? maybe try to track the flow if your code if you have a debugger

Comment: The mistake is easily detectable when you use a debugger or [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to  step through your code.

Comment: As mentioned by Dustinroepsch the issue was the else statement

Comment: Most mistakes are not easily detectible when you first begin programming, but telling someone that they should be is a good way to turn them off programming.

Comment: This was a suggestion how to address relatively simple coding problems and debug code in the future. We are not here primarily to give them a solution, but to enable them to solve their problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the debugger. Trust me If I don't spend hours trying to identify the problem in the code I don't post in stack overflow. After 5 hours I was so tired trying to understand the problem that I decided to post here. The game I am trying to complete is not yet working and I am trying to solve the rest of the problems that the code has.

Comment: @Mr.T many thanks for pointing out the Python Tutor. It really helps to understand where your mistakes are. I wasn't aware of this debugger and I don't think edx has debuggers in Azure notebooks that are being used for the python classes coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your if else statement.

When the input number is not 7, we do not return true, instead we go to the else and immediately return false without checking the rest of the numbers.

The solution is to remove the else, and just return false only after iterating through every cell.

When you change the returns to prints this bug disappears because you are no longer returning, and therefore execution doesn't stop early.

```
def available(location, board):
    for row in board:
        for col in row:
            if col==location:
                return True

    return False
```

The key insight here is that returning from a function, exits the function.

Comment: I would not ever think about this issue. I couldn't imagine that a simple esle statement would cause so much trouble. I spent 5 hours going through the code and rewriting it. Thank you

Comment: No problem! The good thing is after that experience you should be able to catch it pretty quickly next time :)

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the problem you identified, you could for instance flatten your list by using a [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835952/8881141) and check for the existence of `location` in it:

```
board = [['7', '8', '9'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3']]

location = input(" Turn, select a number (1, 9): ")

def available(location, board):
    #collect all elements from all sublists in a list 
    allfields = [i for j in board for i in j]
    #location element of this list?
    if location in allfields:
        return True

    return False

print(available(location,board))
```

Comment: I am not sure if the AI that will check the answer in EDX would accept having the 2D list flattened and decided to not risk it and stick to what information EDX provided me.

Comment: I added a link to an explanation of list comprehensions for educational purposes. And tbh, I learned a great deal about Python from using debuggers and identifying problems in the code. Good luck with your projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any` for a more Pythonic version.

```
def available(location, board):
    return any(any(i == location for i in row) for row in board)
```